# Getting very High Squarred Error Value and Weird Slope

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, machine-learning, linear-regression

i'am building a linear regression model to predict number of bedrooms based on price using the kc_house_data data set from kaggle.I'am trying to implement it from scratch but i get very high squarred error and weird slope.I tried changing it from bedrooms to squre feet of living room and still i get the same error
Here's the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from statistics import mean
import math


df=pd.read_csv('J:/ML/Practice/Data/kc_house_data.csv')


x=np.array(df['price'],dtype=np.float64)
y=np.array(df['bedrooms'],dtype=np.float64)


def slopeIntercept(x,y):
    m=( ((mean(x)*mean(y))-mean(x*y))/((mean(x)*mean(x))-mean(x*x)))
    b=mean(y)-m*(mean(x))
    return m,b
def sqerr(y,y_out):
   sqer=sum((y-y_out)**2)
   return sqer

m,b=slopeIntercept(x,y)

reg=[(m*i+b) for i in x]

print("Error--->",sqerr(y,reg))
print("Slope---->",m)
print("Intercerpt---->",b)
```

Output:

```
Error---> 16917.22171815727
Slope----> 7.811575787151662e-07
Intercerpt----> 2.948947677982094
[Finished in 2.7s]
```

Please HELP.............Anyone!

Comment: I would advice you to check that the linear regression works by using a known case (for example `x = y = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])`. This should return `m = 1, b = 0, sqerr(y, reg) = 0`. If this is the case, you could change the y-array in known ways (for example `y = 2x + 3`). The problem right now is, that the values you get might be totally valid (it says in principle the house prices are independent of the house size, but vary a lot), but there could also be an error in your implementation of the linear regression.

Comment: okay i will check it....thanks for looking into this problem

Comment: i have checked it with value u have suggested,its output is as follows:


`Error---> 0.0
Slope----> 1.0
Intercerpt----> 0.0
[Finished in 3.0s]`

Comment: Then I would suggest you to plot `y` over `x`. This way you can see if there is any linear relationship between the two. As posted before, I assume that the results are totally correct and you simply have a data set which can not be expressed by a linear relationship

Comment: yes you are right!
i have plotted y over x and the graph ressembles a mountain.
I think Clustering Should Work(correct me if iam wrong).
anyway, Thanks for your help :)